# Gatsby replace image by base64 string in html but still serves it in javascript

Tags: base64, gatsby, gatsby-image

I include some small images in my Gatsby website. The resulting html uses base64 strings which is fine. For some reason Gatsby includes exactly the same base64 image strings in component---src-pages-index-js-89ae02357f7d97fc84f9.js.

```
<a key={i} rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" href={"http://www.webworkers.io"}><img
                    alt={`${i} logo`}
                    src={require(`./${i}.png`)}/></a>
```

Can I change this behaviour ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. gatsby-image adds Base64 thumbnails to use the "blur-up" technique for loading images. You can change this behavior or remove it entirely by using a different fragment when querying your image (`GatsbyImageSharpFluid_noBase64` for example - see [the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/)). Is this what you want to achieve? Otherwise, can you elaborate?

Comment: I just figured out the problem. So the image I am using is really small so require(`./${i}.png`) will result in a base64 string which Gatsby includes in the HTML. In the same time Webpack will put the base64 in the resulting .js files. To solve this I have to use the Gatsby Sharp plugin.